# Why is R8 being modified when using ADDS instruction?

Tags: assembly, arm, microprocessors

I am using ARMSIM to test out my Arm Assembly code.

I see R8 being updated for no reason.

This doesn't happen when I use the regular ADD instruction.

I understand ADDS updates the flags but why R8?

[image]

Comment: It's a smulator, and quite an unreliable one. Ditch it.

Comment: Unless an interrupt handler ran between those instructions (which was written not to preserve R8, making it unusable for anything else system wide!), the simulator appears to be buggy.  I assume it actually changed, not just highlighted for no reason in the debugger window?

Comment: Or is it possible that ARM machine code could decode as Thumb or vice versa and be different instructions?  Still not good if this simulator is doing that.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's a simple instruction simulator, not even an emulator.

Comment: I suggest using `FVP` instead. (Fixed Virtual Platform). You can download DS-5 Community Edition that comes with free Cortex-A9 & A53 versions of `FVP` https://img.cs.montana.edu/windows/ds5/

Comment: Now that I think about it I don't see why the carry would be set after that addition either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as how both `IRQ` and `FIQ` are disabled, there's no reason why `r8` should have changed at all. <del>I've noticed that the carry is also set, which shouldn't happen when adding -10 to -10 but would happen if you added -10 to 0 (since this would result in crossing the `FFFFFFFF-00000000` boundary.)</del> I think the comments are right about this being a simulator bug. It would appear that the simulator executed `adds r8,r8,r0` without you asking it to, somehow.

Comment: Are you sure about "...the carry is also set, which *shouldn't happen* when adding -10 to -10 ..."? Doesn't FFFFFFF6 + FFFFFFF6 wraparound?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that was my mistake.